# Is it possible to create a client in PHP for Restlet?

Tags: java, php, rest, restlet

Im developing a java application that provides some methods using restlet to a android app.

I created the server and the client using [this tutorial](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/introduction/first-steps/first-application#android-client) 
(GAE server and Android client)

Now I need to make a PHP client that is able to access that data. Is that possible? What is the best way to do it?

I already tried to get the data using Advanced REST client but restlet always provide a 404 error

Edit: I can use any web language, PHP was used as an example

Comment: Is your goal to consume the REST service running on your server?  If so, isn't this just a matter of accessing a web service?

Comment: yes, my goal is to consume it

Comment: Language is irrelevant. But the CURL functions in PHP allow you to send HTTP requests. 404 errors are usually caused by some incorrect configuration, which leads to pointing to a non-existing web resource.

Comment: Already tried with all URL I could think of, all return 404 so I suspect is something related to how restlet serializes the objects

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a [restlet extension](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/extensions/httpclient)

I hope it helps somebody else ;)

Comment: In fact, the internal HTTP connector for client isn't very stable. You made the right choice to use the HttpClient extension (it also provides an HTTP connector). Notice that switching HTTP connectors for client have no impact on application code...

Answer (score 0):

Restlet provides a way to implement RESTful applications. They are independent from the client so you should be able to consume them with any language.

I would recommend you to enable traces on the server side to find out what happens:

```
Engine.setLogLevel(Level.FINEST);
```

You can try to use curl to have a low-level view of exchanged messages (address / path, headers and payload).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I already have my logs set to ALL, I tried seeing where it pointed and recreating it but didnt work, there might be something about how Restlet serializes things that messes with that approach

Comment: Great! I would need more details to be able to help you. For example, the way you create your restlet application (standalone or in servlet container, use of component and virtualhost, ...), the content of successful requests and of request that fail. Thanks!